# Programação em pares remotamente

Tags: engenharia-de-software, github, ide

Eu e meu parceiro gostamos bastante de programar em pares de vez em quando, geralmente quando se tem alguma função complexa. Mas nós moramos em cidades diferentes e as vezes fica difícil se reunir para programar.

Atualmente estamos desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android com a IDE oficial (Android Studio) configurado com o controle de versões Github.

Ultimamente estamos usando a transmissão de tela pelo Skype para fazer a programação em pares. Está bacana, mas queríamos algo parecido com o que o Google docs faz, ou seja, edições simultâneas.

Há alguma ferramenta ou funcionalidade do Android Studio ou Git que faz isso?

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente a Microsoft anunciou uma ferramenta de colaboração em tempo real: Visual Studio Live Share.

O que é interessante nela:

- Pode ser usada no Visual Studio ou no Code
- Usa o tooling da máquina que faz o compartilhamento da sessão, ou seja, você vai ver o conteúdo das variáveis da máquina chamadora!
- Você vê e pode editar em tempo real o código para ajudar alguém!

Isso é pair programming de uma maneira nunca vista!

Até o momento desta resposta a ferramenta está em preview limitado. Você pode pedir para participar neste link: https://code.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-live-share, clica no botão "Sign up for early access"

Se você conhece alguém que tenha acesso, pode instalar a ferramenta nesse link https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share e pedir para essa pessoa te chamar para uma sessão.

Answer (score 0):

Conheço dois:

- [Screenhero](https://screenhero.com), que é uma solução de compartilhamento de tela, porém via peer-to-peer
- [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://c9.io/), essa sim uma solução mais parecida com a citada, porém, ela funciona na nuvem.